# Solving StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

I received a crash report, which is about `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in ZhuangDictActivity$SearchDicAsyncTask.doInBackground`

Here is the ZhuangDictActivity$SearchDicAsyncTask.doInBackground:

```
private class SearchDicAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        private byte searchStatus;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if (params[0].length() > 0) {
                word = params[0].trim();
                long[] index = null;

                FileAccessor in = null;
                DictZipInputStream din = null;
                try {

                    char key = GB2Alpha.Char2Alpha(word.charAt(0));
                    tableName = DatabaseHelper.transTableName(key);

                    index = databaseHelper.queryTable(tableName, word);

                    if (index != null) {
                        in = new FileAccessor(new File(dictFileName), "r");
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) index[1]];
                        if (isDZDict) {
                            din = new DictZipInputStream(in);
                            DictZipHeader h = din.readHeader();
                            int idx = (int) index[0] / h.getChunkLength();
                            int off = (int) index[0] % h.getChunkLength();
                            long pos = h.getOffsets()[idx];
                            in.seek(pos);
                            byte[] b = new byte[off + (int) index[1]];
                            din.readFully(b);
                            System.arraycopy(b, off, bytes, 0, (int) index[1]);
                        } else {
                            in.seek(index[0]);
                            in.read(bytes);
                        }

                        wordDefinition = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                    } else {
                        searchStatus = 0;
                        return null;
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ffe) {
                    searchStatus = 1;
                    return null;
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    searchStatus = 2;
                    return null;
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (din != null)
                            din.close();
                        if (in != null)
                            in.close();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
            return wordDefinition;
        }  
    }
```

The complete code is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/zhuang-dict/source/browse/trunk/ZhuangDict/src/cn/wangdazhuang/zdict/ZhuangDictActivity.java).
I have limited knowledge in Java and Android development. How should I solve this? I intended to post the complete stack traces but stackoverflow do not allow me to do so because it stated my question has too many code. Anyway, the line which is causing the problem is `char key = GB2Alpha.Char2Alpha(word.charAt(0));`.

Comment: First step is to post here the stacktrace and tell us which line the exception throws. So that we can see whats actually going wrong

Comment: The crash is caused by `char key = GB2Alpha.Char2Alpha(word.charAt(0));`

Comment: And this is GB2Alpha.java: http://code.google.com/p/zhuang-dict/source/browse/trunk/ZhuangDict/src/cn/wangdazhuang/dict/util/GB2Alpha.java?r=21

Comment: As a side note here. Your code will throw an 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException' exception if you pass an empty String array.

Comment: Try simply printing the content of word.charAt(0)

Comment: Sorry, how to print the content of word.charAt(0)?

Comment: See this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html           So for example: Log.i("SearchDicAsyncTask.oInBackground", word.charAt(0));

Comment: I need time to learn how to put the log, probably I will post it on tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: I deleted `char key = GB2Alpha.Char2Alpha(word.charAt(0)); tableName = DatabaseHelper.transTableName(key);`, surprisingly the app is still working. I think this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your string contains only white spaces. meaning it passed the condition:

```
if (params[0].length() > 0)
```

But when you call trim(), these are removed, resulting in an empty stream and an "IndexOutOfBoundsException" exception being thrown when you execute:

```
word.charAt(0)
```

**EDIT**

This is not the reason. After a test, when trim is called on a String with only whitespaces, the String remains unchanged.